# network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized

Tags: docker, kubelet, cni

KubeletNotReady

`runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady
 message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized`

I don't know how to make the network plugin ready

Answer (score 10):

While you run `kubectl describe node <node_name>`
In the **Conditions** table, the `Ready` type will contain this message if you **did not initialized cni**. Proper initialization can be obtained by installing network addon. I will point you to 2 most used: Weave and Flannel

**1)** Weave

```
$ export kubever=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')
$ kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$kubever"
```

After executing those two commands you should see node in status "Ready"

```
$ kubectl get nodes
```

You could also check status

```
$ kubectl get cs
```

**2)** Flannel

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/62e44c867a2846fefb68bd5f178daf4da3095ccb/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

**3)** [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) will explain how install other network addons. In [this](https://chrislovecnm.com/kubernetes/cni/choosing-a-cni-provider/) article each CNI provider have a short description.

Comment: The "cloud.weave.works" website doesn't work. Is any replacement available?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, update systemd from 30.el7_3.9 to 67.el7_7.4 solved this.

Comment: I had installed a cni but still did not show as ready. After I upgraded packages on my nodes, one of which was systemd, they all showed ready.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this error: `container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized`

And when I tried creating a node shell session, I got this error: `Error occurred: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.kyverno.svc-fail": Post "https://kyverno-svc.kyverno.svc:443/validate/fail?timeout=15s": no endpoints available for service "kyverno-svc"`

So, I deleted the following two Kyverno webhooks:

```
validatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io/kyverno-policy-validating-webhook-cfg     1          201d
validatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io/kyverno-resource-validating-webhook-cfg   1          201d
```

After deleting these webhooks, it got fixed. Seems like these webhooks were making the nodes to be unreachable.