# runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, rollback

### Problem you have encountered:

`"runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized"`

### What you expected to happen:

- Upgrade should work
- Roll back should work
- Resize it back to 2 and all services should come up

### Steps to reproduce:

```
Running GKE
Master version 1.14.8-gke.12
Node version: 1.14.8-gke.2
Machine type n1-standard-8
```

running perfectly before this upgrade issue then:

1) 
    
      `gcloud beta container node-pools update k-cpu-pool-v1 --cluster=k --workload-metadata-from-node=GKE_METADATA_SERVER --zone=us-central1-a
      # fails with 2nd node
      gcloud beta container node-pools rollback k-cpu-pool-v1 --cluster=k3 --zone=us-central1-a
      # also fails with 2nd node and many deployment won't come up`

   2)

```
trying to "Enable metadata server" per instruction
https://medium.com/@louisvernon/mapping-kubernetes-service-accounts-to-gcp-iams-using-workload-identity-b53496d543e0 
but blocked by failure of previous deployment
```

### Other information (workarounds you have tried, documentation consulted, etc):

```
I tried looking at google forum issue but nothing.  Looks like a GKE issue with 
rollback when upgrade fails. double issue. Upgrade and master and node to have
same version? 

It doesn't seem to be this issue because one node came up but second does not in GKE.. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675934/network-plugin-is-not-ready-cni-config-uninitialized)
```

Comment: Could you provide full text of commands and errors you've got at every step? Do you have Workload Identity enabled at the cluster level?

Comment: there is no error from running above commands from step1.  the node has older GKE_METADATA_SERVER 1.14.8-gke.2 but still fails with "runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized" in conditions from "gcloud beta container node-pools update k-cpu-pool-v1 --cluster=k --workload-metadata-from-node=GKE_METADATA_SERVER --zone=us-central1-a"

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not clear what happened and why. Please edit your question and provide more details about your steps, decisions and with full text of commands/errors. BTW, you're using BETA function "Workload Identity" and "gcloud beta" commands - they're not as stable as stable ones and I'd rather not use them in production.

Comment: yes. It is beta command and the goal is to fix 403 error trying to access a GCP bucket.  Now I have an error with cni network when autoscaling to more than one node and the deployment of kubeflow is blocked. 
step 1 was to update GKE_METADATA_SERVER to newer code per medium article to use a different running service acocunt to access bucket instead of default service account. Step 2 was to recover from step 1 by rollback.

Comment: It seems you are reporting a bug. I recommend you post this on the google issue tracker

Comment: If your goal is "fix 403 error trying to access a GCP bucket" it'll be better to include this into your post and provide more information. And, as you can see, there's not enough data in your post to help find a solution for you. Please, update your post as I asked you.

Comment: I am trying to not use GCP_CRED...  env with json to access GCP bucket.  So, I am trying to get workload identity to work naturally with gcp.use_gcp_secret(('user-gcp')) in ML pipeline per my understanding in Google NEXT demo (ie) https://youtu.be/TZ1lGrJLEZ0 ..  I already filed a bug in google issue tracker

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to recreate your problem:

1. create cluster and pool:

   ```
   gcloud container clusters create test-cluster --zone us-central1-a --cluster-version 1.14.8-gke.12 --node-version 1.14.8-gke.2 --num-nodes=2

   WARNING: Currently VPC-native is not the default mode during cluster creation. In the future, this will become the default mode and can be disabled using `--no-enable-ip-alias` flag. Use `--[no-]enable-ip-alias` flag to suppress this warning.
   WARNING: Newly created clusters and node-pools will have node auto-upgrade enabled by default. This can be disabled using the `--no-enable-autoupgrade` flag.
   WARNING: Starting in 1.12, default node pools in new clusters will have their legacy Compute Engine instance metadata endpoints disabled by default. To create a cluster with legacy instance metadata endpoints disabled in the default node pool, run `clusters create` with the flag `--metadata disable-legacy-endpoints=true`.
   WARNING: Your Pod address range (`--cluster-ipv4-cidr`) can accommodate at most 1008 node(s). 
   This will enable the autorepair feature for nodes. Please see https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/node-auto-repair for more information on node autorepairs.
   Creating cluster test-cluster in us-central1-a... Cluster is being health-checked (master is healthy)...done.              
   Created [https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/us-central1-a/clusters/test-cluster].
   To inspect the contents of your cluster, go to: https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/workload_/gcloud/us-central1-a/test-cluster?project=test-prj

   NAME LOCATION MASTER_VERSION MASTER_IP MACHINE_TYPE NODE_VERSION NUM_NODES STATUS

   test-cluster us-central1-a 1.14.8-gke.12 XX.XX.75.247 n1-standard-1 1.14.8-gke.2 2 RUNNING
   ```
2. enable Workload Identity (beta) via UI

`Workload Identity Enabled`

3. scale up to 3 nodes

   ```
   gcloud container clusters resize test-cluster --node-pool default-pool --num-nodes=3 --zone=us-central1-a

   Pool [default-pool] for [test-cluster] will be resized to 3.
   Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y
   Resizing test-cluster...done.                                                                                              
   Updated [https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/us-central1-a/clusters/test-cluster].
   ```
4. upgrade nodes

   ```
   gcloud beta container node-pools update default-pool --cluster=test-cluster --workload-metadata-from-node=GKE_METADATA_SERVER --zone=us-central1-a

   Updating node pool default-pool... Done with 3 out of 3 nodes (100.0%): 3 succeeded...done.                                       
   Updated [https://container.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/test-prj/zones/us-central1-a/clusters/test-cluster/nodePools/default-pool].
   ```
5. scale down to 2 nodes

   ```
   cloud container clusters resize test-cluster --node-pool default-pool --num-nodes=2 --zone=us-central1-a

   Pool [default-pool] for [test-cluster] will be resized to 2.
   Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y
   Resizing test-cluster...done.                                                                                              
   Updated [https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/us-central1-a/clusters/test-cluster].
   ```
6. disable Workload Identity (beta)
   6.1. at first you should go to`Kubernetes clusters` click on your cluster -> at `Clusters` go to `Node pools` then click on `default-pool` and then `Edit node pool` -> `Edit default-pool` -> go to `Security` and uncheck `Enable GKE Metadata Server (beta)`.
   6.2. and after that go to `Kubernetes clusters` click on your cluster -> at `Clusters` click on `Edit` and set `Workload Identity (beta)` as `Disabled`.

I've checked all this commands on my test cluster and found no errors or network issues. After that I've tried to repeat steps 2-5  and then rollback:

```
gcloud beta container node-pools rollback default-pool --cluster=test-cluster --zone=us-central1-a  

Node Pool: [default-pool], of Cluster: [test-cluster] will be 
rolled back to previous configuration. This operation is long-running 
and will block other operations on the cluster (including delete) 
until it has run to completion.

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Rolling back default-pool... Done with 1 out of 2 nodes (50.0%): 1 being processed, 1 succeeded...done.                           
Updated [https://container.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/test-prj/zones/us-central1-a/clusters/test-cluster/nodePools/default-pool].
operationId: operation-1577965484794-e4b2b2a6
projectId: test-prj
zone: us-central1-a
```

There was no errors and network problems also. And then I was able to disable Workload Identity (beta) via UI as I described in step 6.

It looks like everything works good and there's some specific problem in your configuration.

Comment: I am waiting for istio manual addon configuration information that is affecting all updates

Comment: I haven't noticed any information about istio configuration in your question.