# How to fix Cilium CrashLoopBackOff on minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I installed Meshery with Helm.

All pods are ok except the Cilium

```
meshery-app-mesh-7d8cb57c85-cfk7j                   1/1     Running            0                63m
meshery-cilium-69b4f7d6c5-t9w55                     0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   16 (3m16s ago)   63m
meshery-consul-67669c97cc-hxvlz                     1/1     Running            0                64m
meshery-istio-687c7ff5bc-bn8mq                      1/1     Running            0                63m
meshery-kuma-66f947b988-887hm                       1/1     Running            0                63m
meshery-linkerd-854975dcb9-rsgtl                    1/1     Running            0                63m
meshery-nginx-sm-55675f57b5-xfpgz                   1/1     Running            0                63m
```

Logs show

```
level=info msg="Registering workloads with Meshery Server for version v1.14.0-snapshot.4" app=cilium-adapter
panic: interface conversion: error is *fs.PathError, not *errors.Error

goroutine 42 [running]:
github.com/layer5io/meshkit/errors.GetCode({0x278e020?, 0xc0004f7e30?})
```

I checked events also

```
kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.name=meshery-cilium-69b4f7d6c5-t9w55
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON    OBJECT                                MESSAGE
17m         Normal    Pulling   pod/meshery-cilium-69b4f7d6c5-t9w55   Pulling image "layer5/meshery-cilium:stable-latest"
2m44s       Warning   BackOff   pod/meshery-cilium-69b4f7d6c5-t9w55   Back-off restarting failed container meshery-cilium in pod meshery-cilium-69b4f7d6c5-t9w55_default(d7ccd0e8-27e5-4f40-89bc-f8a6dc8fa25a)
```

I am adding logs from troubled pod
Events:

```
  Type     Reason           Age                    From     Message
  ----     ------           ----                   ----     -------
  Normal   Pulling          4h25m (x55 over 8h)    kubelet  Pulling image "layer5/meshery-cilium:stable-latest"
  Warning  BackOff          3h45m (x1340 over 8h)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container meshery-cilium in pod meshery-cilium-69b4f7d6c5-t9w55_default(d7ccd0e8-27e5-4f40-89bc-f8a6dc8fa25a)
  Warning  FailedMount      21m (x6 over 21m)      kubelet  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "kube-api-access-tcdml" : object "default"/"kube-root-ca.crt" not registered
  Warning  NetworkNotReady  20m (x19 over 21m)     kubelet  network is not ready: container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
  Warning  BackOff          72s (x82 over 19m)     kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container meshery-cilium in pod meshery-cilium-69b4f7d6c5-t9w55_default(d7ccd0e8-27e5-4f40-89bc-f8a6dc8fa25a)
```

The Nginx pod shows network problems

```
Events:
  Type     Reason           Age                 From             Message
  ----     ------           ----                ----             -------
  Warning  NodeNotReady     22m                 node-controller  Node is not ready
  Warning  NetworkNotReady  22m (x18 over 23m)  kubelet          network is not ready: container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
  Warning  FailedMount      22m (x7 over 23m)   kubelet          MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "kube-api-access-lscv2" : object "default"/"kube-root-ca.crt" not registered
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As per this [Blog](https://www.blinkops.com/blog/troubleshooting-the-crashloopbackoff-error) by Patrick Londa, your cilium Pod is getting `CrashLoopBack off` error due to the `"Back-off restarting failed container"`, this means that your container suddenly terminated after Kubernetes started it.   
1. This occurs due to the temporary resource overload as a result of a spike in activity. The solution to fix this is to **adjust periodSeconds or timeoutSeconds** to give the application a longer window of time to respond.   
2. Sometimes this happens due to insufficient memory resources. You can increase the memory limit by **changing the "resources:limits"** in the Container's resource manifest as shown in the blog.   
Verify the above steps and let me know if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Take a look at my edit.pls!

Comment: As per this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67386884/19230181) by Sebastian Posada, he solved this issue by installing the [Pod network add-on](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) this overlay network which satisfies the kubernetes requirements. Can you have a try and let me know if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Flannel does not change anything,it createsits own namespace. Meshery uses cilium. I will show all addons.

Comment: Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56344613/19230181) and [GIT Link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1031) for more information.